How to disable TAB key in ContextMenuStrip?
I have a simple and old windows forms app with a MenuStrip and ContextMenuStrip and I need that the TAB key doesn't iterate thru the items, it has to be just the arrow keys.
I've tried setting TabStop = True but it doesn't seem to affect the controls.
Any ideas how I could do this easily?
I tried setting TabStop both in designer and code, both true and false on both controls MenuStrip and ContextMenuStrip but they do not seem to have any effect. Also set TabIndex for menustrip to 0 to see if that made any difference but no.
I also tried this, but when I'm navigating with arrows in contextMenuStrip, and then hit tab it doesn't seem enter this method, it only enters the method when I hit tab in the top menu strip and not all items (those without submenus)
    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
        if (keyData == Keys.Tab && (this.ActiveControl == this.menuStrip1 || this.ActiveControl == this.contextMenuStrip1))
        {
                    return true;

OR:
this.KeyPreview = true;
this.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(Form1_KeyDown);

And then in Keydown, e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
Nothing changes the behavior inside the ContextMenuStrip...

I'd try to handle Control.PreviewKeyDown and suppress TAB.

Tks, I've tryed that but apparently doesn't do anything within the ContextMenuStrip.
My app is very old and basic (.net 4.8), I used the designer to create the form and add the MenuStrip and ContextMenuStrip.
I added this to the constructor of my class that inherits from Form:
this.KeyPreview = true;
this.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(Form1_KeyDown);
And then method:
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Tab)
e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
I believe this is what you suggested no?

You cannot use ProcessCmdKey, the menus live on their own turf. You need to implement IMessagefilter, handle PrefilterMessage to check whether the affected Control of a WM_KEYDOWN message is of type ToolStripDropDown when (Keys)m.WParam.ToInt32() == Keys.Tab -- Are you sure you actually need this? What problem are you trying to solve?

@Jimi tks. I just have a stupid requirement, in menu TAB key shouldn't work, you should use the arrow keys to navigate.
That worked! Copilot did it very quickly tks a lot!

To disable Tab-key in menus you need to handle PreviewKeyDown and set e.IsInputKey, this seems to prevent selection logic from running.
There is a problem with sub-menus, because each drop-down has its own event, which you need to handle.
If menu is created, then you can find all sub-menus recusively and subscribe each, something like this:
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    DisableTabKeyRecursive(contextMenuStrip1);

    void DisableTabKeyRecursive(ToolStripDropDown menu)
    {
        menu.PreviewKeyDown += (s, e) =>
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Tab)
                e.IsInputKey = true;
        };

        foreach (ToolStripMenuItem item in menu.Items)
            if (item.HasDropDown)
                DisableTabKeyRecursive(item.DropDown);
    }
}

